# Gettext or database translation

Tags: php, mysql, translation, gettext

Which is better:

1. gettext
2. custom MySQL+cache based functionality

Gettext is a sort of builtin feature, so I assume it's tweaked for performance. Using poedit is a pain and impossible to show to any client.

A custom functionality allows for simple translation interface. But might be heavy on php/db usage.

I suppose, which one would you use when?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Localization is difficult. It is really difficult. It's not just `"pairs of words" => "Wortpaare"`, it's a lot more complex than that. What most people forget when they look at gettext and go *"Ugh, ugly"* is that the localization *process* is a lot more important than the technical details of the implementation. That's because the actual translators are typically not programmers and are probably not even in-house. This causes a lot more headaches than you may think. gettext is really old, is battle tested and has a huge toolchain behind it that is tuned to support this process. If you want to do i18n and l10n properly, you need a powerful system. gettext is that and has support from a wide range of tools. Your Homebrewed Translation System™ does not.

First of all, you need a robust system to *extract* translatable strings. Without being able to automatically and reproducibly extract translatable strings from source code, you have a mountain of work for each new string you want to translate. In gettext, `xgettext` does that.

Next, you need a tool to synchronize the extracted strings with already existing translations in a way that no translations are lost and that only slightly changed translations are kept if possible. In gettext, `msgmerge` does that.

Next, you want a way to add extra information to strings. You want to be able to group them by category, "domain" and context, you may want to add comments for the translator to the source code and you may want translators to be able to add comments to the translations. gettext supports all that.

Next, you want a file format that has good support from a variety of tools, since you may be sending your files to China to get them translated there. The reason you may be sending them away to external translators is also the reason you need a good synching tool to merge changes, since this can be a very asynchronous process. PO files are very well supported, because gettext is so old. There are many open source and commercial tools that support the localization process at many levels, depending on your specific needs.

Do not underestimate the task of localization, choose a tool that is well suited for the process and learn it. gettext is a great tool, if admittedly not the most beginner friendly.

For what it's worth, here's [my gettext extension for Twig](https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions/blob/master/doc/gettext.rst), which makes gettext for PHP even better.

Comment: Great answer - thank you for pointing out the little issues that crop up with a homegrown solution.  While a custom solution would work initially for most, as a project grows in complexity/number of languages supported, it sounds like the custom solution would end up being abandoned in favor of a full gettext implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look into [Memcached](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/memcached/) which you can use it in combination with MySQL.
It's very useful for fetching data which doesn't change too often, like translations.

Answer (score 2):

Gettext is a very old format. Its using files to store translations. Its clumsy, especially when you have translations by the thousands lets say 20,000. Managing a PO file with 20,000 translation strings is a nightmare, across 50 languages is imposible. Then you have to actually compile it in a MO file. No thanks. It might have made sense back in the 1990, not now.

Databases instead are powerful. Like really powerful. Name what you need and you can get it. In a second they can tell you exactly:

- Which of the translation strings are not translated in which language
- When was the translation first created and by whom
- When was the translation last updated and by whom
- Full history of every translation with person who has done the change
- You can have all texts pre-translated in materialized views and get them with one select statement
- Order translation strings in alphabetic order, in pages for page by page view and edit
- Set which user can update exactly which translations
- With some simple HTML web forms, anyone anywhere in the world can translate your application in real time, within seconds, and with full history, comment on every translation pair, recieve and read replies, flag translations for todo, etc, etc
- Have analytics in seconds of who has made how many translations, in the last day, week, month, year - so you can give incentives out
- Still want PO files? You can get these created by your database on a schedule that you need them
- Missing translations? Your database can send automatic emails, SMS to the responsible translator for this language.
- A translation has been updated by the translator? Now the database can send an email to the responsible reviewer to approve
- Need the translation fast? Your database can call an API to have it translated right now, then send email to the responsible person to review