# Translation alternatives to constants on PHP

Tags: php, cookies, translation

I've been working in translations for customly designed webs for a while and those needed translations, so what I'm currently doing for translating the text is the following:

I have multiple files that have a bunch of PHP files that contain the strings in multiple languages. Each file has the same constant declared exactly the same. Like this:

```
define('MENU_ITEM1','WHO ARE WE?');
define('MENU_ITEM2','PROFESSIONAL ACTIVITY');

define('MENU_ITEM1','¿QUIÉN SOMOS?');
define('MENU_ITEM2','ACTIVIDAD PROFESIONAL ');
```

Then, on the menu I have the language selector. The select creates a get variable on the url displaying the selected language, like this:

```
<select id="select" onChange="idioma(this.value);"> 
        <option value="ES">Español (ES)</option>
        <option value="EN">English (EN)</option>
        ...
</select>
```

This calls a function that adds a get to the url. Like this (for every language):

```
location.href=url+"?lang=ES";
```

So in another file, we have a PHP switch that takes the language from the url and creates a cookie that includes the right language file. If the cookie is not set, we have a default language. It would be something like this:

```
<?php 

if(isSet($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

     $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));

    }else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    }else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])){
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }else{
        $lang = 'ES';
    }

switch ($lang) {

    case 'EN':
    $lang_file = 'en/lang.en.php'; 
    break;

    case 'ES':
    $lang_file = 'es/lang.es.php'; 
    break;

    default:
    $lang_file = 'es/lang.es.php';

}

include_once $lang_file;
```

?>

So by this teeeedious process, the web is traslated. **Issue**: I have the slight feeling that this is not an optimal solution, so if anyone has a way to fix it or do it in any other way, it would be so helpful. Note that I do not work with WordPress, so WP plugins are out of the question (I worked with them, I know they exist). I've seen webs that use subdomains (`en.something.com`) or other folders (`something.com/en/`) but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341460/gettext-or-database-translation/15343103#15343103

Comment: You should use something other than constants as your i18n system. The bit of code to set up the locale shouldn't be a big deal whatever you use, but constants are pretty primitive for the task of storing l10ns.

Answer (score 0):

Trust me I've been there before. I've written functionality for a website that now uses more than 5 languages.

In my approach I used CSV files (Comma-Separated Values).
You could start your development with the following code.

Your Spanish translation file `es.csv`

```
'Home', 'Inicio'
'Page 1', 'Pagina 1'
'Page 2', 'Pagina 2'
'Page 3', 'Pagina 3'
```

The first column of words would be your default language which would be defined within a function.

```
<a href="#"><?php __("Home"); ?>
```

Then you would use a switch statement like the one you have on top to capture which language the user choose. The `__()` function would look something like this. Where input would be "home"

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
// Logic (where it would do the translation)
// It could look for the input in the $cvs variable if it exist then use the next value of the current array. Else keep the text the same.
```

Your cvs file would need to make the exact words to be translated

I hope this makes sense.