# Include problems with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, include

I need a little help! I'm making multilangual site with php and I got an issue. I want to include array into another array.

There is one php file

```
<?php
$lang = array(
    'en' => array(
        include ('translations/nav-translation/en.php');
    ),
    'lv' => array(
        include ('translations/nav-translation/lv.php');
    ),
);
?>
```

And php file that I want to include

```
<?php
 "home" => "Home",
 "blog" => "Blog",
 "about" => "About me",
?>
```

Comment: What are you currently having issues with? Can you show us the error you are having?

Comment: When open website it shows just white blank page and in console it says "Failed to load resource".

Comment: You can't include files this way

Comment: I'm not any kind of PHP expert (although I do use it), but my understanding is that `include` is a statement, so needs to be followed by a semicolon. So try replacing the `,` with a `;` - although I can't guarantee it will work even then.

Comment: @John Conde is there other way?

Comment: @Robin Zigmond thanks but it didn't work :(

Comment: @KristersDzintars I would suggest creating a PHP function that checks what language is chosen, once you do that you load a PHP file with the contents of an array called text, and this array will be the correct text to display.

Comment: I would really suggest using yaml, and then reading them with [symfony's yaml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html) component. then you can munge them together much more easily.

Comment: @DevDonkey +1 for munging stuff together

Comment: there should be quotes (if anything) in your `include (translations/nav-translation/XX.php)`. You should be getting parse errors with error reporting enabled. I.e.: `include ('translations/nav-translation/XX.php')`, on top of the trailing comma in `"about" => "About me",`. Yet, as John stated; that isn't how to include files. Your best bet is to include the files in a switch case instead.

Comment: Each PHP file needs to be fully formed PHP code in itself. You cannot spread partial PHP code snippets around and "glue them together" with `include`. That's not how that works.

Comment: @KristersDzintars check my answer if you have Database access, also try removing the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343103/476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just set up your include files like this:

**translations/nav-translation/en.php**

```
<?php
    $lang['en'] = array(
        "home" => "Home",
        "blog" => "Blog",
        "about" => "About me"
    );
?>
```

And then:

```
<?php
    $lang = array();

    include ('translations/nav-translation/en.php');
    include ('translations/nav-translation/lv.php');

?>
```

Seems a lot less complicated than any other suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use yaml it's better to return arrays from your lang files

en.php:

```
<?php
 return ["home" => "Home",....]
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$lang = array(
    'en' => include("translations/nav-translation/en.php"),
    'lv' => ....
```

Comment: You *may* have to do `(include '...')`; it's not a function and parentheses don't work the same way with it.

Comment: And if i want to include more files in that 'en' array?

Comment: Here's the thing, if you are only going to load one set of language-specific data for a given user, then it is wasteful to load the `$lang` array with "everything you got".  Determine the desired language, check if that one language has a file associated with it (have a fallback language), then only access the one desired file.

Answer (score 0):

To create a multilingual PHP site, I'd suggest using a function that checks the language the user has specified and then loading the text from a database or use JSON.

**Using JSON**

Create a file with a .txt extension, create your translations in JSON format and read it via PHP, to read the file in PHP use:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),TRUE);
```

You can then use the JSON data to set variables within PHP to display the correct language.

**Using a database**

Have your database setup like this:

```
   ---------------------------
   Lang   |   Short   |   Text
   ---------------------------
```

In your database, set up as many languages as you want, have the lang column the two-letter abbreviation of the language name, the short should be the name of the text, so if it was the home page title, name the short `home-title` and then the text should be the text that you want to be displayed in your desired language.

Using a database will allow you to add/edit languages and translations via the database.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Will try using db. It'll bet my first time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'translations/nav-translation';
$user_lang = 'nl';  // determine what the user actually wants
$fallback_lang = 'en';
if (file_exists("{$path}/{$user_lang}.php")) {
    include ("{$path}/{$user_lang}.php");
} else {
    include ("{$path}/{$fallback_lang}.php");  // nominate a default
}
```

In the language files (e.g. `translations/nav-translation/en.php`), offer a fully formed associative array:

```
$lang = [
    "home" => "Home",
    "blog" => "Blog",
    "about" => "About me"
];
```

---

Then, back in your original file after the conditional include call, you can reference `$lang['home']` or *[cringe]* use `extract()`* to generate variables like `$home`.

*note, I have never, ever used `extract()` in any of my projects, there are risks in using it -- I'm just saying you *could*.